# Planar graph drawing C++

Tags: c++, graph

I have read many articles on drawing planar graphs on the plane, I tried a lot of libraries.

In the end, I need to specify the input graph, the output to obtain new coordinates of its vertices, so that the edges do not intersect.

The choice fell on the function **chrobak_payne_straight_line_drawing** from Boost Graph Library.

I tested it on the following graph: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/attachments/cplusplus-programming/11153d1322430048-graph-planarization-boost-library-1grb.jpg

But it did not work and calls **System.AccessViolationException** at the 125 line of file chrobak_payne_drawing.hpp:

```
delta_x[v3] = 1;
```

But on this graph it works: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/attachments/cplusplus-programming/11154d1322430090-graph-planarization-boost-library-2gr.jpg

Please help, I need to function to work with all planar graphs and does not cause critical errors. Below I present the code, which I tested the first graph and got a critical error, by the way, I'm using visual studio 2010.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
    #include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stack>

    #include <boost/graph/planar_canonical_ordering.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/is_straight_line_drawing.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/chrobak_payne_drawing.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/boyer_myrvold_planar_test.hpp>

    using namespace boost;

    //a class to hold the coordinates of the straight line embedding
    struct coord_t
    {
      std::size_t x;
      std::size_t y;
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      typedef adjacency_list
        < vecS,
          vecS,
          undirectedS,
          property<vertex_index_t, int>
        > graph;  

      //Define the storage type for the planar embedding
      typedef std::vector< std::vector< graph_traits<graph>::edge_descriptor > > 
        embedding_storage_t;
      typedef boost::iterator_property_map
        < embedding_storage_t::iterator, 
          property_map<graph, vertex_index_t>::type 
        >
        embedding_t;

      // Create the graph - a maximal planar graph on 7 vertices. The functions
      // planar_canonical_ordering and chrobak_payne_straight_line_drawing both
      // require a maximal planar graph. If you start with a graph that isn't
      // maximal planar (or you're not sure), you can use the functions
      // make_connected, make_biconnected_planar, and make_maximal planar in
      // sequence to add a set of edges to any undirected planar graph to make
      // it maximal planar.

      graph g(5);
      add_edge(0,3, g);
      add_edge(0,4, g);
      add_edge(1,3, g);
      add_edge(1,4, g);
      add_edge(2,3, g);
      add_edge(2,4, g);

      // Create the planar embedding
      embedding_storage_t embedding_storage(num_vertices(g));
      embedding_t embedding(embedding_storage.begin(), get(vertex_index,g));

      boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(boyer_myrvold_params::graph = g,
                                   boyer_myrvold_params::embedding = embedding
                                   );



      // Find a canonical ordering
      std::vector<graph_traits<graph>::vertex_descriptor> ordering;
      planar_canonical_ordering(g, embedding, std::back_inserter(ordering));


      //Set up a property map to hold the mapping from vertices to coord_t's
      typedef std::vector< coord_t > straight_line_drawing_storage_t;
      typedef boost::iterator_property_map
        < straight_line_drawing_storage_t::iterator, 
          property_map<graph, vertex_index_t>::type 
        >
        straight_line_drawing_t;

      straight_line_drawing_storage_t straight_line_drawing_storage
        (num_vertices(g));
      straight_line_drawing_t straight_line_drawing
        (straight_line_drawing_storage.begin(), 
         get(vertex_index,g)
         );



      // Compute the straight line drawing
      chrobak_payne_straight_line_drawing(g, 
                                          embedding, 
                                          ordering.begin(),
                                          ordering.end(),
                                          straight_line_drawing
                                          );



      std::cout << "The straight line drawing is: " << std::endl;
      graph_traits<graph>::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
      for(tie(vi,vi_end) = vertices(g); vi != vi_end; ++vi)
        {
          coord_t coord(get(straight_line_drawing,*vi));
          std::cout << *vi << " -> (" << coord.x << ", " << coord.y << ")" 
                    << std::endl;
        }

      // Verify that the drawing is actually a plane drawing
      if (is_straight_line_drawing(g, straight_line_drawing))
       std::cout << "Is a plane drawing." << std::endl;
      else
        std::cout << "Is not a plane drawing." << std::endl;
      return 0;  
    }
```

Mayber i must first make graph maximal planar? But I did not succeed .. Please help me add to my code the necessary functions for this, I'm not quite sure what step to convert the graph.

Thanks in advance, you - my last hope!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in boost::graph. I have a different access violation there, perhaps because of a different boost version, but there's definitely a bug.

```
        left[v] = right[leftmost];
        vertex_t next_to_rightmost;
        for(vertex_t temp = leftmost; temp != rightmost;
            temp = right[temp]
            )
          {
            next_to_rightmost = temp;
          }

        right[next_to_rightmost] = graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex();
```

Here when `leftmost==rightmost`, the `for` loop is not executed and `next_to_rightmost` remains uninitialized. Crash! That's what I'm seeing.

Comment: I do not think this is a bug, it says that before using chrobak_payne_straight_line_drawing, you must first use the three functions in series, make_connected, make_biconnected_planar, and make_maximal, but I did not get it all together in a code, with nothing and ask for help. Most likely these errors are due to the fact that the graph is passed not maximal planar..

Answer (score 0):

The graph you were using was not maximal planar. You need to use the functions make_connected, make_biconnected_planar and make_maximal_planar before you get to a canonical ordering or an embedding. Though the comment in the source explains this, their use is not exactly intuitive and I could not find a source using them and the function chrobak_payne_straight_line_drawing in combination. [Here is an example I adapted from the original source and other examples](https://github.com/benmsisson/chrobak_embedding).