# Boost C++ - Ordering size not the same as graph size

Tags: c++, boost, graph

As a follow up to my question [Boost graph segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477876/boost-graph-segmentation-fault) and to the older question [Planar graph drawing C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299363/planar-graph-drawing-c), I have a planar graph in Boost that is not maximal planar but it has at least three edges. I call [make_connected](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/make_connected.html), [make_biconnected_planar](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/make_biconnected_planar.html) and [make_maximal_planar](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/graph/doc/make_maximal_planar.html) on it so that it should now be maximal planar.

When I call [planar_canonical_ordering](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_canonical_ordering.html) on it, the ordering should be the same size as the original graph, but it is not for certain graphs, which causes a segmentation fault in [chrobak_payne_straight_line_drawing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/straight_line_drawing.html) because the ordering is of size < 3.

What I don't understand is why the planar canonical ordering is not the same size as the graph itself. Certainly, there are specific edges that could be added to the graph to increase its ordering size, as noted in the answer to the first question, but that is not a general case. If the graph is maximal planar, why is its ordering (ordering.size()) not the same size as the graph (num_vertices(g)) itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although as in [Boost graph segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477876/boost-graph-segmentation-fault) I was calling all the functions necessary to make the graph maximal planar, I was not storing the vertices in the graph.

To do this, use:

```
edge_count = 0;
for(boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = edges(g); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
    put(e_index, *ei, edge_count++);
```

A completed example of starting with a singly connected graph and then embedding it can be found [here](https://github.com/benmsisson/chrobak_embedding).